# How to iterate over an multidimensional arbitrary list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, iterator

I have an expression Tree, that generates the Tree list. The list variers depending on the expression that are used to calculate the number for example,

> T =  ['-', ['+', ['-', 75, ['-', 10, 3]], ['-', 100, 50]], 3]

Or

> T =  ['+', ['*', 5, 4] ,['-', 100, ['/', 20, 2] ]]

I want to iterate over each and every element of the Tree and store the index of the operators, list of all the operators, index of the numbers and the list of numbers in an array. For this, I am trying to figure out a way that I can loop into the list and then just check if the type is a string which would mean it is an operator and store that index and value in the respective array by appending, else if the type is number then store it in the array with all the numbers.

I tried the below code

```
T = T =  ['-', ['+', ['-', 75, ['-', 10, 3]], ['-', 100, 50]], 3]
for i in range(0,len(T)):
    if type(T[i]) != int:
        for j in range(0,len(T[i])):
            print(T[i][j])
    else:
        print(T[i])
```

Running the code gives the output:

```
-
+
['-', 75, ['-', 10, 3]]
['-', 100, 50]
3
```

What we are basically trying to achieve is to go inside the list till we could depending on the list size. Any ideas on how this could be possible?

My answer would basically be:

```
address list of the operators is  [[0], [1, 0], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 2, 0], [1, 2, 0]] 
    
list of the operators is ['-', '+', '-', '-', '-'] 
    
address of the numbers is [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2], [2]] 
    
list of the numbers is [75, 10, 3, 100, 50, 3]
```

Comment: Read up on *recursion*.

Comment: @Mark just edited the question, the expected output is at the end of the post, essentially all the 4 list of indexes of numbers and operators and their value.

Comment: @ScottHunter how would I be able to get information about the index if I am doing recursion? for suppose sometimes the index is [0], but sometimes it has to be [1, 1, 0] or [1, 1, 2, 0] (from the output expected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursive functions. The following can be improved, for example by processing operators and numbers simultaneously.

```py
T = ['-', ['+', ['-', 75, ['-', 10, 3]], ['-', 100, 50]], 3]

def evaluate(arg): # not requested, but why not?
    if type(arg) is list:
        return eval(f'{evaluate(arg[1])} {arg[0]} {evaluate(arg[2])}')
    else:
        return arg

def get_ops(arg): # returns (list of operators, list of their indices)
    ops = [arg[0]] # first elem is an operator, so add it
    idx = [[0]] # add this index 0
    for i in (1, 2): # for each position 1 and 2,
        if type(arg[i]) is list: # if NOT scalar
            ops_sub, idx_sub = get_ops(arg[i]) # recurse!
            ops += ops_sub # add the list of ops from the sublist
            idx += [[i] + x for x in idx_sub] # add idx list from the sublist,
                                              # while the position of the sublist
                                              # being PREPENDED to each idx
    return ops, idx

def get_nums(arg): # basically the same goes here
    nums = []
    idx = []
    for i in (1, 2):
        if type(arg[i]) is list:
            nums_sub, idx_sub = get_nums(arg[i])
            nums += nums_sub
            idx += [[i] + x for x in idx_sub]
        else: # if scalar, this IS a number, so add it to the output
            nums.append(arg[i])
            idx.append([i])
    return nums, idx

print(get_ops(T))
print(get_nums(T))
print(evaluate(T))
```

The result:

```
(['-', '+', '-', '-', '-'], [[0], [1, 0], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 2, 0], [1, 2, 0]])
([75, 10, 3, 100, 50, 3], [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2], [2]])
115
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, the code does work for 3-4 different trees that I tried with. :)

Comment: @Nihar Glad it helped! It was a fun exercise.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single recursive generator function with `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def get_ops(t, p = []):
   if isinstance(t, int):
      yield ('val', t, p)
   else:
      yield ('op', t[0], p+[0])
      yield from get_ops(t[1], p+[1])
      yield from get_ops(t[2], p+[2])

T, d = ['-', ['+', ['-', 75, ['-', 10, 3]], ['-', 100, 50]], 3], defaultdict(list)
for a, b, c in get_ops(T):
    d[f'{a}_index'].append(c)
    d[f'{a}s'].append(b)

print(dict(d))
```

Output:

```
{
  'op_index': [[0], [1, 0], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 2, 0], [1, 2, 0]], 
  'ops': ['-', '+', '-', '-', '-'], 
  'val_index': [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2], [2]], 
  'vals': [75, 10, 3, 100, 50, 3]
}
```

Comment: @Nihar Glad to help!